# Do actions granted by the Haste spell count as "your action"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions

I asked a similar question "[How do the Haste spell and Turn Undead interact?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154584)". Perhaps I'm wrong, but it seems that the answer there says that even [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste)'s action is limited by Turn Undead, that Turn Undead controls not just your action but also *haste*'s action as it is **still an action**.

I'm wondering then how this works with other features, such as the [*witch bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/witch-bolt) spell, which states:

> [...] The spell ends if you **use your action** to do anything else [...]

Since Turn Undead has control over *haste*'s action, does *witch bolt* have control over it as well, meaning that *witch bolt* would end if you use *haste*'s action?

Or there's the [Charger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/charger) feat (PHB, p. 165), which states:

> When you **use your action to Dash**, you can use a bonus action to make one melee weapon attack or to shove a creature [...]

Would taking the Dash action using *haste's* action qualify and this grant you the bonus action?

And the cleric's [Channel Divinity](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#ChannelDivinity-110) option Turn Undead, already explicitly asked about [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154584), states:

> A turned creature [...] also can’t take reactions. **For its action**, it can use only the Dash action or try to escape from an effect that prevents it from moving. If there’s nowhere to move, the creature can use the Dodge action.

Does Turn Undead force even *haste*'s action to become restricted? (The answer there seems to be "yes".)

Also of note is that the above features use different wording from things such as the [*fear*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fear) spell, which states:

> [...] A creature must **take the Dash action** [...]

As discussed in the question "[Can you do anything other than Dashing while affected by fear?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123164)", this wording *does* allow you to use *haste*'s action instead of your "standard" action. How does the difference in wording affect these sorts of things?

How does the action granted by the *haste* spell interact with these sorts of features?

I'm wondering if expanding this question to also include Action Surge makes it too broad, though I don't see why the features would work any differently.

Comment: Fear is using the word "action" to mean "option" (among the various actions a character can choose to take) so it's not quite the same as your other examples. I might suggest doing away with that one because it clouds the issue a little.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Haste grants an additional action (but limits the use of it)

*Haste* says says (emphasis added):

> Until the spell ends, the target's speed is doubled, it gains a +2 bonus to AC, it has advantage on Dexterity saving throws, and it gains **additional action** on each of its turns. That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

The fact that you get an "additional" action indicates that this action is no different than your "normal" action, except for the limitations described in the next sentence. Nothing in those limitations turns the action into anything other than an action. Hence, it is an action, and it is yours, so it is your action, just as much as your normal action is. Note that *Haste* uses the same wording as the fighter's [Action Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ActionSurge-193), which unambiguously grants you a 2nd action that is indistinguishable from your first action:

> On your turn, you can take one **additional action**.

As for how the additional action granted by *Haste* interacts with the other effects you've mentioned:

#### *Witch Bolt*

A literal reading of the spell suggests that yes, using the action granted by *Haste* to do anything would cause *Witch Bolt* to end. You could justify this logically by saying that maintaining *Witch Bolt* requires nearly all of your attention, leaving only your bonus action to do something else. However, [Rykara's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/154599/40516) to the question that you linked makes the point that the rules are typically written for the common case of only 1 action without regard for exceptions. As such, it wouldn't be unreasonable for a DM to rule that *Witch Bolt* is maintained as long as you spend *one* of your actions on each turn to maintain it, allowing you to take other actions while maintaining the spell.

#### Charger

If you take the Dash action using the action granted by *Haste*, you have used your action to dash, which means you have satisfied the requirements to use your bonus action to make an attack as described in the feat. It doesn't matter which action you used to dash.

#### Turn Undead vs *Fear*

As described in the linked question, Turn Undead sets limits on what actions an affected creature may take, only allowing them to Dash, attempt to escape from something, and sometimes Dodge. In contrast, a literal reading of *Fear* just says that you must take *one* Dash action on each of your turns while frightened. It doesn't say that you can't do anything else, so once you've taken the Dash action and used all your movement to flee from the caster, you have done everything the spell requires you to do, and you are free to use the rest of your turn, even if the rest of your turn includes one or more actions (although you are still limited by the frightened condition).

Of course, for a creature that has only one action, the two wordings are effectively equivalent, so it feels a bit unsatisfying that granting an additional action causes them to diverge, especially in light of the observation mentioned above that most rules are only written for the case of having a single action. As DM, you can either accept that different effects sometimes work differently in certain situations for no logical reason, or you can house rule it by choosing one or the other interpretation and applying it to all similar "forced to flee" effects: either you are forced to take one Dash action, or all your actions must used to dash.

### Having multiple actions makes the rules ambiguous

Ultimately, you are correct that the rules are a bit under-specified and ambiguous in cases where a creature can take multiple actions in a turn. "Your action" is unambiguous when you have one action, but once you gain multiple actions, **nothing in the rules specifies whether "your action" should generalize to "all of your actions" or "one of your actions".** In some cases, a literal reading of a specific effect appears to prefer one or the other interpretation, but in general there is no way to solve this unambiguously. 5th edition intentionally avoids using the rules to spell out the resolution of every weird edge case. Instead, it delegates the task of resolving those edge cases to the DM.

Comment: Could you analyse this from a “specific beats general” POV?

Comment: @DaleM I'm not sure there's a useful conclusion the draw here from the "specific beats general" principle. All these effects are written for the general case of having one action per turn, and the more specific case is having additional actions. However, the effects that cause this more specific case don't provide any guidance on how they should interact with or override effects written for the general case. So the DM is left to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning under Fear that you’re not quite free to do anything you like - the frightened condition imposes the restriction that you can’t willingly move closer to the source of your fear.